# Receive a list of names and return a list of users - HackerRank test

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, programming-challenge

So, few months ago I did a HackerRank test for a company. The problem was to create a function which receive a list of names and returns a list of unique usernames. For example:

For the list of `names = ['john', 'john', 'tom', 'john']`
The function must return: `= ['john', 'john1', 'tom', 'john2']`

My code was:

```
def username_system(u, memo={}, users=[]):
    copy_u = u.copy()
    try:
        name = copy_u[0]
    except IndexError:
        return users
    if name in memo.keys():
        memo[name] += 1
        username = name + str(memo[name])
        users.append(username)
        copy_u.remove(name)
        return username_system(copy_u, memo, users)
    else:
        username = name
        users.append(username)
        memo.update({name: 0})
        copy_u.remove(name)
        return username_system(copy_u, memo, users)
    return users
```

I'd like to know,  what could I improve in this code? I used memoization to make it faster. Also, I think this code is in O(n), but I'm not sure. Is that right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would warn you from using such an approach - it may lead to *buggy* and ***unexpected*** results.
Consider the following situation:

```
names = ['john', 'john', 'tom', 'john']
res1 = username_system(names)
print(res1)    # ['john', 'john1', 'tom', 'john2']

lst = ['a']
res2 = username_system(names, users=lst)
print(res2)   # ['a', 'john3', 'john4', 'tom1', 'john5']
```

Looking at the 2nd `print` result ...
Using a *mutable* data structures as function default arguments is considered as a fragile approach - Python "memorizes"(retains) that mutable arguments content/value between subsequent function's calls. Furthermore, you use 2 of such.
Though in some cases it may be viable for defining a specific internal recursive functions - I'd suggest a more robust and faster approach.

As you're mentioned about *"memoization", "to make it faster", "O(N)"* here's a *deterministic profiling* stats for your initial function:

```
import cProfile

# def username_system(...)
names = ['john', 'john', 'tom', 'john']
cProfile.run('username_system(names)')
```

Output:

```
         27 function calls (23 primitive calls) in 0.000 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>)
      5/1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 test.py:3(username_system)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'copy' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'keys' of 'dict' objects}
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'remove' of 'list' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'update' of 'dict' objects}
```

As you may observe even for that simple input list of 4 names `username_system` function is called 5 times.

---

Instead, we'll rely on supplementary [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) object that conveniently provides the *initial* value.
Then, traversing over a copy of initial user names only entries that occur more than **1** time (within a dict keys view) will be appended with *incremented ordinal suffix*:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def get_unique_usernames(user_names):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    uniq_unames = user_names[:]

    for i, name in enumerate(uniq_unames):
        if name in d:
           uniq_unames[i] += str(d[name])
        d[name] += 1

    return uniq_unames


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    names = ['john', 'john', 'tom', 'john']
    print(get_unique_usernames(names))    # ['john', 'john1', 'tom', 'john2']
```

---

Comparison of *Time execution* performance:

*initial setup:*

```
from timeit import timeit

names = ['john', 'john', 'tom', 'john']
```

---

**`username_system`** function:

```
print(timeit('username_system(names)', 'from __main__ import names, username_system', number=10000))
0.027410352995502762
```

**`get_unique_usernames`** function:

```
print(timeit('get_unique_usernames(names)', 'from __main__ import names, get_unique_usernames', number=10000))
0.013344291000976227
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was of great help!

Comment: This fails for `get_unique_usernames(['john', 'john', 'john1'])` (it returns `['john', 'john1', 'john1']`).

Comment: @FlorianBrucker, such a condition (if relevant) should be stated in the OP's question as a specific *edge* case

Answer (score 4):

## Recursion

Recursion is a bad idea if a simple loop does the job and if you have little control over recursion depth.

```
In [1]: import sys
In [2]: sys.getrecursionlimit()
Out[2]: 1000
```

Of course you can set a higher limit, but you may run into a stack overflow. But lets refactor your code first.

## Code repetition

Code repetition is one of the ugliest things you can do. copy pasted code is a real pitfall when you forget o update the other execution paths. We change

```
def username_system(u, memo={}, users=[]):
    copy_u = u.copy()
    try:
        name = copy_u[0]
    except IndexError:
        return users
    if name in memo.keys():
        memo[name] += 1
        username = name + str(memo[name])
        users.append(username)
        copy_u.remove(name)
        return username_system(copy_u, memo, users)
    else:
        username = name
        users.append(username)
        memo.update({name: 0})
        copy_u.remove(name)
        return username_system(copy_u, memo, users)
    return users
```

to

```
def username_system(u, memo={}, users=[]):
    copy_u = u.copy()
    try:
        name = copy_u[0]
    except IndexError:
        return users
    if name in memo.keys():
        memo[name] += 1
        username = name + str(memo[name])
    else:
        memo.update({name: 0})
        username = name
    users.append(username)
    copy_u.remove(name)
    return username_system(copy_u, memo, users)
    return users
```

We immediately see the unreachable code at the end and remove the last line

## Try/catch instead of if/else

You misuse exception handling for a simple test. We replace

```
try:
    name = copy_u[0]
except IndexError:
    return users
```

by

```
if len(copy_u) == 0:
    return users
name = copy_u[0]
```

## Avoid unnecessary copies

Where you iterate over your list you do

```
copy_u = u.copy()
```

for no reason. This your absolute performance killer as it is of quadratic complexity. We can delete that line and the code is still working. If we want to save the initial list we do

```
print(username_system(names.copy()))
```

in our main function.

## Be careful about remove()

`list.remove()` searches(!) for a value and deletes it from the list. You already know which index to delete, so use `del`.
In your case `remove()`has no negative impact to complexity as the element is found immediately at the front. However the code is more readable when you use `del` as this tells everybody that no search is done.

Current status

```
def username_system(u, memo={}, users=[]):
    if len(u) == 0:
        return users

    name = u[0]
    if name in memo.keys():
        memo[name] += 1
        username = name + str(memo[name])
    else:
        memo.update({name: 0})
        username = name
    users.append(username)
    del u[0]
    return username_system(u, memo, users)
```

## And now the subtle bug

If you call your function multiple times there is some persistence

```
print("given:", names)
print("returns:", username_system(names.copy()))
print("given:", names)
print("returns:", username_system(names.copy()))
```

prints

```
given: ['john', 'john', 'tom', 'john']
returns: ['john', 'john1', 'tom', 'john2']
given: ['john', 'john', 'tom', 'john']
returns: ['john', 'john1', 'tom', 'john2', 'john3', 'john4', 'tom1', 'john5']
```

How is that? You do default params in your function. This default value is created only once. If you alter the value, which is possible on containers like `list` the altered value persists. When you call your function the second time `memo`and `users` are initialized to the previously used objects and continue the up-count. That can be solved like

```
def username_system(u, memo=None, users=None):
    memo = memo or {}
    users = users or []
```

## Some other python stuff

```
if name in memo.keys():
```

can be replaced by

```
if name in memo:
```

The default iteration over a `dict()` gives the keys. Use `dict.keys` only if you e. g. want to copy keys to a list().

In the module `collections` there is a class `Counter` which does exactly what your `memo` does. We use it like

```
from collections import Counter

def username_system(u, memo=None, users=None):
    memo = memo or Counter()
    users = users or []
    # [...]
    if name in memo:
        username = name + str(memo[name])
    else:
        username = name
    memo[name] += 1
```

Comment: You have an extra `return` in your second code block under "Code Repetition"

Comment: @Gloweye: Right. And  I have an extra line in the text that says that 'We immediately see the unreachable code at the end and remove the last line'.  :-)

Comment: Ah, ok. Perhaps I read a bit to quickly :)

Comment: Thank you! That was an amazing answer!

Answer (score 2):

- [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) gives you a major headstart on this one.
- Include some """python [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)"""
- decompose into a neat single username method and a [list-comprehension](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-list-comprehensions-in-python-3) to apply this to an input list.

The below is not self-contained (`users` resides as a global variable) but solves the problem succinctly.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

users = defaultdict(lambda: -1)  # All names start at -1


def new_username(name):
    """Generate unique username for given name"""
    users[name] += 1
    return f"{name}{'' if users[name] == 0 else users[name]}"


def username_system(names):
    return [new_username(n) for n in names]  # list comprehension


names = ['john', 'john', 'tom', 'john']
print(username_system(names))
```

Comment: This fails for `username_system(['john', 'john', 'john1'])` (it returns `['john', 'john1', 'john1']`).

Comment: Interesting. Given the input is a "list of names" I'm going to assume the only missed code here is to validate input name is only alphabetical characters - john1 is not a name (unless you're a rapper)

Comment: Yes, it was just a list of names.